# Update state in onBeforeRouteUpdate()

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router4

I'm a newbie and working with translation software, thanks for the guidance.

I have a routing component that updates count in `onBeforeRouteUpdate()` every time I navigate, it works fine, but the `onUpdated()` hook is called twice, and I don't understand why. Is there any way to avoid it?

Code:

```js
<template>
  <div>{{count}}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onUpdated } from 'vue'
import { onBeforeRouteUpdate } from 'vue-router'

const count = ref(0)
onUpdated(() => console.log('updated'))

onBeforeRouteUpdate((to, from) => {
  count.value += 1
})
</script>
```

output twice in the console

[image: img1]

Comment: Did you tried use the **beforeRouteEnter** ? Maybe it can resolve your problem.

Comment: @Alexandre Heinen Thank you, still don't understand why, but I guess `async feth()` caused the component to update again after Update, but my project was not affected, maybe it's designed that way.